# Using CreateDirectory to dynamically create a web folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, create-directory

. .

I'm working on retrofitting an ASP.NET application using a C# back-end.  I'm trying to develop a file uploader to work with CKEditor.

I have an <asp:FileUpload> object that I'm using to search for a file, and a TextBox object (for this purpose, let's say the TextBox ID = "SaveTo") where the user enters the filename and path where (s)he wants the file saved.  The default is a folder I define in my Web.config (let's say it's "/Images/Saved" -- note: this is an *existing* folder off my web root).

So, if I run my code and save a file (let's say it's "SomeImage.jpg"), the content of my SaveTo text box is "/Images/Saved/SomeImage.jpg".  My code then uses the text box content to save to /Images/Saved/SomeImage.jpg.  That piece works fine.

Here's where I run into trouble: I want my code to dynamically generate a folder if the user enters "/Images/Saved/SomeFolder/SomeImage.jpg".  In other words, if "SomeFolder" does not exist in "/Images/Saved", I want to create it.

It's not working out very well.  It does not create the folder, and it saves the file to the default /Images/Saved folder.

With that, I have a couple of questions.

1. I'm trying to use Directory.CreateDirectory to do this.  Can I get away with using a web-root-relative directory (like "/Images/Saved"), or do I need to fully-qualify it?
2. If I need to fully-qualify it, can I use the URL (e.g. "http://www.mysite.com/Images/Saved"), or do I need the physical file path (e.g. "c:\wwwroot\Images\saved")?

Here's my code snippet:

```
if (this.MyFileUpload.HasFile) {
    string SaveFile = "";
    string SavePath = this.SaveTo.Text.Trim();

    if (!SavePath.EndsWith("/")) { SavePath += "/"; }

// I'm guessing that I'll need to change "/" to "\" and fully qualify the path
    getFileName = this.MyFileUpload.FileName;
    SaveFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~" + SavePath) + getFileName;
    try
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo getFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(SaveFile);
        getFile.Directory.Create();
        this.MyFileUpload.SaveAs(SaveFile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        txtMessage.Text = getFileName + " save failed.  " + ex.Message;
    }
    txtMessage.Text = "File " + getFileName + " saved successfully!";
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work. Maybe the SaveTo.Text has the incorrect path?

Comment: Well, that's the point.  By default, the path in SaveTo.Text is (using my example) /Images/Saved.  If someone enters /Images/Saved/SomeFolder, I want it to create SomeFolder under /Images/Saved.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (this.MyFileUpload.HasFile) {
    string SaveAs = this.SaveTo.Text.Trim().Replace('\\','/');
    string SaveFile = SaveAs;
    // Pull SavePath from web.config (should check that key exists first)
    string SavePath = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveDirectory"];
    string SystemPath = string.Empty;

     // Handle case where SaveAs contains directory
    if (SaveAs.LastIndexOf("/") > -1) {
        SavePath = SavePath.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + SaveAs.Substring(0,SaveAs.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        SaveFile = SaveFile.Substring(SaveFile.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    }

    if (!SavePath.EndsWith("/"))  
        SavePath += "/"; 

    // Find the system path 
    SystemPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(SavePath);

    // Ensure the system path exists
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(SystemPath))
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SystemPath);

    // Ensure a filename was entered, if not use original file name
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SaveFile))
        SaveFile = MyFileUpload.FileName;

    try
    {
        this.MyFileUpload.SaveAs(SystemPath + SaveFile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        txtMessage.Text = getFileName + " save failed.  " + ex.Message;
    }
    txtMessage.Text = "File " + getFileName + " saved successfully!";
}
```

Comment: Let me take some time to digest this and incorporate it into my code.  I'll let you know how it goes.